# Can stack tell you how many visitors you have had?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

Can stack tell you how many visitors you have had?

Comment: stack what? stackoverflow? stackexchange? you mean views?

Comment: I think he wants to know if a stack of dog poo on your porch can tell you how many people have stepped in it (aka visitors).  I would vote to close as not trilogy related.

Comment: @I am Chet Atwood: Really?  I'd vote as belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for http://meta.stackexchange.com